# url_for() parameter was ignored in flask

Tags: python, flask

My route method is:

```
@app.route('/movie/')
def movie(page_num=1):
#...detail skipped...
```

And my template is:

```
<li><a href="{{ url_for('movie',page_num=page_num) }}">{{ page_num }}</a></li>
```

When I click the link, the address bar shows *"127.0.0.1:5000/movie/?page_num=5"*,but the *pagination.page* shows it is still page 1.

Why the parameter was ignored and how can I fix it?

Comment: sounds like your pagination logic is broken, not the `url_for` call

Comment: shouldn't 127.0.0.1:5000/movie/?page_num=5 be 127.0.0.1:5000/movie?page_num=5, try removing the extra backslash in you're route /movie/ => /movie

Comment: I tried removing the backslash artificially,but the backslash appeared again.@reticentroot

Comment: I also tried print page_num before pagination init,and the page_num is still 1.Is there anyplace that could break the pagination logic?@AnthonySottile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you skipped the code of your function it's hard to say what's wrong. But I suspect that you just don't catch GET parameters correctly. To do this you can either use [variable rules](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#variable-rules) with dynamic name component in your route; or access parameters submitted in the URL with `request.args.get`.

Here's a minimal example showing boths methods:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    link = url_for('movie',page_num=5)
    return "<a href='{0}'>Click</a>".format(link)

@app.route('/index2')
def index_get():
    link = url_for('movie_get',page_num=5)
    return "<a href='{0}'>Click</a>".format(link)


@app.route('/movie/<page_num>')
def movie(page_num=1):
    return str(page_num)

@app.route('/movie_get')
def movie_get():
    param = request.args.get('page_num', '1')
    return str(param)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Yes!! I found that I didn't catch the GET paramater and *request.args.get* really helps. And is it that I can only use *url_for* to call the movie method?

Comment: @YanchengZeng calling function with `url_for`this is what you'd most likely do with a routing function that supposed to render templates and have pagination. But I think it's better if you post another specific question with what you are trying to achieve with you `movie` function.

Comment: This example of routing to /movie_get worked great for the case of clicking an HREF link. However, what if I want my GET to be in a form? For example:  `<form action="/movie_get?page_num=365" method="GET"><input type="submit" value="Load Next"></form>`. This didn't print 365 to the screen. It printed `'1'`. Why?